# jQuery Missing ")" in Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to display a loader for when my images are loading. The loader is pure css. For some reason, the line noted below is throwing an error for missing ), but it is there. I am no js expert, so I am likely missing something obvious however does anyone have any idea what is causing this? Here is the code for my loader and the jQuery. Is this even the proper way to do it, or is there a better way? I am trying to replace loading images with the loader div and then hide the loader and display the image.

JS:

```
// jQuery Wrap

(function($) {

// Lazy Loading



// Image Loader

$("img:not(.site-branding, .mobile-header img)").each(function (){
    $(this).after('<div class="loader"></div>')
        .hide()
/* The line below is causing the error. :( */
        .attr('src', this.src;)
        .one('load', function() {
        $(this).fadeIn().next().remove();
        });
});

// Mobile Menu

$('.hamburger').on('click', function () {

    $('.mobile-navigation').toggleClass('open');

});


// End jQuery Wrap

})( jQuery );
```

Loader CSS:

```
.loader {
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    animation: spinner 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spinner {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: change `.attr('src', this.src;)` to `.attr('src', this.src)` no need to coma

Answer (score 6):

This line

```
.attr('src', this.src;)
```

should be

```
.attr('src', this.src)
```

The `;` is totally wrong there. Even on the end of the line, because you chain `.one()` right behind.

Comment: Can we merge answers as exact duplicates ;)?

Comment: and you dont need coma ;) `on` get called after attr

Comment: @John, you're right. So we got four, exact copies of the same incorrect answer.

Comment: Correct, @John! Edited!

Comment: Its a simple typo error. A comment would have sufficed.

Comment: Looks like everyone is having a fun time :')

Answer (score 0):

You should change that:

```
.attr('src', this.src;)
```

To this:

```
.attr('src', this.src)
```

EDIT: Removed the ';' because the chain is continued. Haven't seen that before.